# Book with a girl whose grandma is a phoenix, cover depicts the emerald/green-eyed blonde girl

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book in 2016, but I remember the cover being torn up, so it couldn't have been a new book. There was a girl's face on the cover. She had lightly colored skin, and beautiful emerald green eyes. Her hair was a dirty blond. This book was first in a trilogy and the cover was illustrated.

The girl's grandmother in the story was actually a phoenix (I think this was revealed in a different book in the trilogy though). The book started out in a small village, and I can't remember exactly where in the village chapters (the chapters that took place in the village) but she sneaked her deceased mother's green dress out of a trunk she wasn't supposed to go in, and I think she wore it to some event.

Comment: This one is proving difficult to search for. I found [*The Green Dress*](https://www.amazon.com/Green-Dress-Michelle-L-Rusk/dp/0983777624) about a blonde with a deceased relative in Phoenix (the city) where she finds a green dress. Right keywords, wrong story.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**This is Elissa's Quest**, the first book of the Phoenix Rising series. The book in which her grandmother is revealed to be the phoenix is the third book, World's End.

The covers of the books essentially show all the information in your question:

[image]

Blond girl, light skin, very green eyes.

[image]

Green dress, phoenix.

Comment: Thank you! That's the one!