# Fantasy book: redhead girl talks to animals, is made to stay with her noble father, discovers she's part of a phoenix rebirth cycle

Tags: story-identification, books

The main points I remember is that this red haired, green eyed girl is able to talk with animals. She lives with an old lady in the beginning of the book as her mom had died and her father left.

The father, who ends up being a noble of some sort, comes for her, intending to use her as a bargaining chip in his interactions with another noble. While she’s there she has her first period and the noble she was made to stay with tries to force her to be another of his many wives. A young girl helps her escape and they travel around.

The young girl that helps her has water based power.
She gets separated from her friend and meets a boy, who is a prince, and has fire powers.

They discover that they are part of a cycle for the Phoenix to be reborn. And the Phoenix turns out to be the old lady that raised the main character.

Comment: possibly the same as [Book with a girl whose grandma is a phoenix, cover depicts the emerald/green-eyed blonde girl](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/208571/book-with-a-girl-whose-grandma-is-a-phoenix-cover-depicts-the-emerald-green-eye)

Answer (score 5):

Almost certainly *Elissa's Quest* (2007), book 1 of the *Phoenix Rising* series by Erica Verrillo.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1268916.Elissa_s_Quest):

> THIRTEEN-YEAR-OLD ELISSA LEADS a solitary life. She knows nothing of her parents—only that her mother is dead. **Her caretaker, Nana, keeps her father's identity a secret from her. Meanwhile Elissa carries her own secret—the people of the valley must not know that she has the gift of speaking to animals**. For now she is just a healer's apprentice in peaceful High Crossing, but Elissa dreams of a more exciting life, and of, one day, finding her father.
>
> **When an unexpected royal guest arrives at the Manor, Elissa's life changes forever. She leaves home with him, only to discover that she's become a pawn in a battle for his kingdom**. Accompanied by her dear donkey, Gertrude, she is delivered to the evil Khan. Elissa's quest for freedom and the truth about her past leads to questions about the future. **Is she the key to a prophecy—the prophecy of the Phoenix—that everyone seems to know about, except her?**

---

Remembered from [Book with a girl whose grandma is a phoenix, cover depicts the emerald/green-eyed blonde girl](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/208571/), more specifically the details you gave reminded me of the asker's description:

> The girl's grandmother in the story was actually a phoenix (I think this was revealed in a different book in the trilogy though).